# How to open a HTML file on remote machine on local browser

Tags: html, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I have written a simple HTML file on an EC2 instance. I want to check if it functions as desired. Is there a way I can open it on my local browser for testing?

**EDIT:** The output depends on some configurations which are present only on the remote machine!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install and start apache, placing the HTML vile in the www directory on the sever. Then open port 80 in your ec2 security group, but specify this rule to only be for the public IP of your home machine.

Answer (score 0):

If its a HTML file you can open it directly from your desktop but if is a php file you need local server such as Xampp or wamp. If you want to edit it you can have a code editor such as notepad++ ect.. Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you correctly. .. just open the file.   It will run in your browser. It is just text.   It is your browser that runs it.

Comment: the output depends on some configurations which are present only in the remote machine

Comment: He makes no mention of a web server or Security Group settings, simply opening it in his browser won't work unless he's set it up properly.